# Use 'is or 'was' for imagined situation

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct way to write this - it's an imagined, hypothetical situation:

> How would you help a client who was suicidal?

Or is it

> How would you help a client who is suicidal?

Comment: The use of _was_ allows for situations where the client is no longer suicidal.

Comment: @KillingTime or should that be "...who had been suicidal"?  It's not as simple as it looks.